# Scrolling of fixed sidebar where dynamically contents are generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two columns, left column is main feed and right column is sidebar.

I want to scroll each columns separately.

In this case left pain scroll works well.

However right pain scroll doesn't works.

Contents in right panel are dynamically generated by javascript,
so it's sometimes getting longer than screen.

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 60px;" >

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

    Main Feed

    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" 
    style="overflow-y: auto;display: block;position:fixed;right:10px;">

    sidebar content this contents is generated dynamically by javascript

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set the height of right panel fixed and make "overflow: auto"

Comment: Set max height for the div with dynamic content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" 
     style="overflow-y: auto;
            display: block;
            max-height:100vh;
            right:10px;
            position: fixed;">
</div>
```

Check https://codepen.io/ashishkrtewari/pen/BaaJXWy

I just added some generated content and max-height of 100vh. Without a max height you will not see the scrollbar as there is nothing restricting the height to reveal a scrollbar.

Please check

Comment: `max-height:100vh;` gives me a great trick!!!! thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help. @whitebear